# Is there vowel harmony in the way to pronounce re-?

Tags: pronunciation, vowel-harmony

Example: I noticed yesterday that in 'reheat' it is pronounced /i/ but in 'recollect' it is pronounced more like /ɛ/.

Comment: "reheat" means "heat again", but "recollect" doesn't mean "collect again" (ordinarily, but it it does, "re-" is pronounced [ri]).

Comment: does recollect not have a sense of again in it like the word remember?

Comment: Yes. As the ordinary sense of "recollect" does not mean collect again, so "remember" does not mean member again.

Comment: And the specific meaning correlating to (after re-) again isn't what I'm asking for. I'm on about the specific use of re- as the morpheme with the meaning again

Comment: Both "recollect" and "remember" contain the Latin prefix re "again".

Comment: From recolligere and rememorari .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, no - vowel harmony is a property of a language, not a subset of words. Even so, there are many counter-examples to show this doesn't occur with re- words:

- require, research, resource, rely, relay, retrace, return, review... etc

For words with a prefix 're-', the pronunciation falls into ~three categories with mostly predictable pronunciation of the first syllable. Your examples coincidentally happen to have the same vowel in their other syllables:

---

## /ri/

**re + verb = redoing verb**
**stress on second syllable**

- rebuff (v.) /riːˈbʌf/
- recapture (v.) /riːˈkæptjʊɚ/
  -redress (v.²) /riːˈdrɛs/
- remake (v.) /riːˈmeɪk/
- reunion (n.) /riːˈjuːnɪən/
- revisit (v.) /riːˈvɪzɪt/

## /ri/

**stress on first syllable**

- remake (n.) /ˈriːmeɪk/

---

## /rɪ/

**re + verb = different from just redoing verb**
**stress on second syllable**

- rebuff (v.) /rɪˈbʌf/
- redact (v.) /rɪˈdækt/
- redress (v.¹) /rɪˈdrɛs/
- refect (v.) /rɪˈfɛkt/
- resolve (n.) /rɪˈzɒlv/
- resounding (ppl. a.) /rɪˈzaʊndɪŋ/
- retrieval (v.) /rɪˈtriːvəl/

---

## /rɛ/

**re + non-extant verb**
**stress on third syllable**

- resurrect (v.) /rɛzəˈrɛkt/
- revolutionize (v.) /rɛvəˈl(j)uːʃənaɪz/

---

Excluding French etc loanwords with non-nativised pronunciation (e.g. recherché, relevé etc).

---

See here for more info:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181862/is-there-any-rule-for-pronouncing-words-beginning-with-re
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364388/doesnt-english-have-vowel-harmony